# spring aop log full object before deleteById

Tags: spring, aop

in my Project I am using  spring Aop

in before deleteById I want log full object
but in joinPoint.getArgs() return id only not full object

can help me?

```
 public void deletePointcut(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

}
```

Comment: Not without retrieving the object before deleting it. The method only has an `id` not a full object.

Comment: @M.Deinum how to retrieve the full object?

Comment: You would need to inject the entitymanager and manually retrieve it. However that would probably severly impact the performance of your application. What is the usecase you are trying to fulfill?

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to log full object in mongo DB

Comment: Well as stated, retrieve it using the technology you are using then store it where you want. But as mentioned it will probably severely impact your performance of the delete.